# Joining Multiple tables based on a unique ID in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I am wanting to join multiple tables based on a ID I fetch from the first table.

Here is an example:

Location:

| ID | City_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 92418 |

Pro Sport Teams:

| City_ID | Professional_Team_Count | Participant_Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 92418 | 3 | 75 |

Non Pro Sport Teams Table:

| City_ID | Non_Pro_Team_Count | Participant_Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 92418 | 25 | 750 |

I am trying to return a table that looks like this
Result Table

| ID | City_ID | Professional_Team_Count | Non_Pro_Team_Count | Participant_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 92418 | 3 | NULL | 75 |
| 1 | 92418 | NULL | 25 | 750 |

Comment: Both of your "answers" make a rather significant assumption. Do you see it? Perhaps you even make the same one yourself because your sample data is very simplistic. What happens when both tables contain a row with the same LocationID and ProductID values?

Comment: This won't happen because a product with a serial number is unique.

Answer (score 2):

```
select loc.Id, loc.locationId, s.ProductId, s.SerialNumber, null as Quantity   
from Location loc
inner join Serialized s on loc.LocationId = s.locationId
where loc.Id = 1
union all
select loc.Id, loc.locationId, ns.ProductId, null, ns.Quantity   
from Location loc
inner join nonSerialized ns on loc.LocationId = ns.locationId
where loc.Id = 1
```

would do it. You need to union data from 2 sets of data.

Comment: Using `union all` would avoid the extra processing to eliminate duplicate rows. I'm not absolutely convinced that duplicates can't occur, but that's up to the OP's knowledge of their data.

Comment: @HABO, might be but already duplicates wouldn't occur unless it is highly bad designed data. I edited to add all anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**To avoid joining `Location` multiple times**, you can put the `UNION ALL` inside a derived table

```sql
select
  loc.Id,
  loc.locationId,
  s.ProductId,
  s.SerialNumber,
  s.Quantity   
from Location loc
inner join (
    select
      s.locationId,
      s.SerialNumber,
      null as Quantity
    from Serialized s
    union all
    select
      ns.locationId,
      null,
      ns.Quantity
    from nonSerialized ns
) s on loc.LocationId = s.locationId
where loc.Id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a union, to get the rows from both tables:

```
select loc.ID, loc.LocationID, s.ProductID, s.SerialNumber, 
       null as Quantity
  from Location loc
  join Serialized s on s.ID = loc.ID
union all
select loc.ID, loc.LocationID, ns.ProductID, null as SerialNumber, 
       ns.Quantity
  from Location loc
  join NonSerialized ns on ns.ID = loc.ID
```